# Count occurence of a string in a list and display it in console

Tags: c#, linq, file

I'm creating a Logparser right now i'm able to go trought all the file in a folder line by line and extracting the substring i wanted which is the value after `"fct="`. All that using `Regex` and i put the result in a `List`.
Now i want to `Count` the occurence of every string in my list and display it.

I'm using GroupBy but when i display the result all the occurence are at `1`.

**Actual:**

```
 720 1x
 720 1x
 710 1x
```

And it should be:

```
 720 2x
 710 1x
```

I was able to find that the problem is that i read my file line by line so if the `"fct="` value is not twice on the same line it won't count it a `2` but only at `1` for every line that its appears.

So i need to find a way to count my list and not my file line by line.

I'm really beginner so not sure how to do this any tips would be appreciated.

Here's the log data example:

```
<dat>FCT=10019,XN=KEY,CN=ROHWEPJQSKAUMDUC</dat></logurl>
<dat>XN=KEY,CN=RTU FCT=4515</dat>LBZ=test.sqi</logurl>
<dat>XN=KEY,CN=RT</dat>FCT=10019</logurl>
```

I want to display:

```
 FCT=10019 2x
 FCT=4515 1x
```

**My Code:**

```
   class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int counter = 0;
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/LogParser/LogParserV1", "*.txt");
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:/LogParser/LogParserV1/test.txt");      
        char[] delimiters = { '<', ',', '&', ':', ' ', '\\', '\'' };
        string patternfct = "(?<=FCT=)[0-9]*";


        foreach (string fileName in dirs)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);

            {
                String lineRead;
                while ((lineRead = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    //To find all the value of fct= occurence 
                    var listfct = Regex.Matches(lineRead, patternfct, 
  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();


                   var fctGroups = listfct.GroupBy(i => i);
                    foreach (var grp in fctGroups)
                    {
                        var fct = grp.Key;
                        var total = grp.Count();
                        System.Console.WriteLine("fct=" + fct + " " + "Total=" + total);
                    }

                    counter++;
                }
                System.Console.WriteLine(fileName);

                sr.Close();
                sw.Close();
            }
        }

        // Suspend the screen.  
        System.Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you provide *log data* you are parsing?

Comment: So your code is able to count your text, but line by line. And you want to count by file by file? You just need to have a local variable countText, and accumulate it countText += grp.Count() in while loop.

Comment: Select((x,i) => new { value = x.Value, index = i}).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try querying data with a help of Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=FCT=)[0-9]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var records = Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(@"C:/LogParser/LogParserV1", "*.txt")
  .SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file))
  .SelectMany(line => regex
     .Matches(line)
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Select(match => match.Value))
  .GroupBy(number => number)
  .Select(group => $"FCT={group.Key} {group.Count()}x");

foreach (string record in records)
  Console.WriteLine(record);
```

**Demo:** We can't mimic directory and files, so I've removed

```
  Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(@"C:/LogParser/LogParserV1", "*.txt")
    .SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file))
```

but added `testLines`

```
  string[] testLines = new string[] {
    "<dat>FCT=10019,XN=KEY,CN=ROHWEPJQSKAUMDUC</dat></logurl>",
    "<dat>XN=KEY,CN=RTU FCT=4515</dat>LBZ=test.sqi</logurl>",
    "<dat>XN=KEY,CN=RT</dat>FCT=10019</logurl>",
  };

  Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=FCT=)[0-9]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

  var records = testLines
    .SelectMany(line => regex
       .Matches(line)
       .Cast<Match>()
       .Select(match => match.Value))
    .GroupBy(number => number)
    .Select(group => $"FCT={group.Key} {group.Count()}x");

  foreach (string record in records)
    Console.WriteLine(record);
```

**Outcome:**

```
FCT=10019 2x
FCT=4515 1x
```

**Edit:** If you want to include `file` into `records`, you can use anonymous objects:

```
var records = Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(@"C:/LogParser/LogParserV1", "*.txt")
  .SelectMany(file => File
     .ReadLines(file)
     .Select(line => new {
        file = file,
        line = line,  
      }))
  .SelectMany(item => regex
     .Matches(item.line)
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Select(match => new {
        file   = item.file,
        number = match.Value  
      }))
  .GroupBy(item => new {
     file   = item.file, 
     number = item.number
   })
  .OrderBy(group => group.Key.file)
  .ThenBy(group => group.Key.number)
  .Select(group => $"{group.Key.file} has FCT={group.Key.number} {group.Count()}x")
```

Comment: @Joel Deslauriers: I'm sorry for the typo, it should be `.EnumerateFiles` instead of `EnumerateDirectories`

Comment: I only see one thing that do not seems to work i need the FCT= to ignore the case sensitive i used to use RegexOptions.Ignorecase but i cant seems to place it in your query any idea ?

Comment: @Joel Deslauriers: `Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=FCT=)[0-9]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` I've edited the answer

Comment: Great it work fine but also i was able to get the name of each file using Directory.GetFiles do you know if i can do the same with EnumerateFiles?

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` return files one after one, when `GetFiles` obtain *all* the files and return them as an array. We don't want to wait until all the files are got (`GetFiles`) we can start from the very first file (`EnumerateFiles`)

Comment: thanks for the explication i understand the difference now but  since EnumeraFiles return file one by one is there anyway to display in which file the value was found?

Comment: @Joel Deslauriers: yes, you can do it, but, please, note, that you *aggregate* (`GroupBy`) all the patterns; imagine that `FCT=10019` appears *3 times* in `a.txt`, *24 times* in `b.txt` and once in `c.txt`. What should be the output then?

Comment: this is a good point i need to count it by file what i mean is that in the name of each file i have the date so my goal is to parse the date from the file name and after that count the "fct=" value by file name which will also be my date. At the end i should get one result like  FileNameA - 10019 - 3  and FileNameB - 10019 -1